# Target 5 vector_math directory imports empty

Tags: dart

I'm following along the "Game of Darts" tutorial. I followed the instructions but I'm stuck at "Import libraries from a package". The vector_math dir appears empty after I save the pubspec.yaml file. Am I missing a step or is there a work around?

Thanks,
Adolfo

Comment: I asked the author of that tutorial to take a look at your question.

Comment: Might not be relevant, but what operating system on you on?  The tutorial appears to be on a Mac.  I use windows and I am not able to expand installed libraries in the packages directory.  But since importing the library works just fine, didn't think much of it.  Can you import and access methods from the vector_math library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the tutorial and could not reproduce the problem. Here are a few suggestions: make sure that you are using the latest version of Dart Editor (go to `About Dart Editor` in the main `Dart Editor` menu and make sure that your Editor is up to date.

Also, try closing the `vector_victor` files and collapsing the opened folders in the left bar and then reopen them. Does that do anything?

Finally, try running `pub update` and see if that does anything.

The suggestions above all seem a little arbitrary, but its hard to solve a problem that I am not able to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run "pub install" or use "Tools > Pub Install" in Dart Editor?